# Formating Date from parameter in BIRT

Tags: java, parameters, format, birt

Hi so my report takes in a startDate string parameter with the value of "2017/03/18" being passed in. I need to take that and format it to be 18 March 2017.

I've tried using formatter.format(params["startDate"].value,'dd MMM yyy'); but it still doesn't work. I've also used the Format DateTime in the properties tab and it also doesn't work.

Any ideas on how I can convert it to the format I want to?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First You need to convert string date to Date object and then convert the date to String in the  format you need.

```
       //Before Java 8   
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");          
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");           
        String startDate = "2017/03/18";            
        Date sDate =  sdf.parse(startDate);         
        String convertedDate = sdf1.format(sDate);

       // Using Java 8 LocalDate & DateTimeFormatter
        DateTimeFormatter  formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
        DateTimeFormatter  formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy");
        LocalDate ldateTime = LocalDate.parse(startDate,formatter);
        String formattedDate = ldateTime.format(formatter1);
```

Comment: It should work as long as your expression builder provides the supported format. Go through the SimpleDateFormat & DateTimeFormatter API's for more info.